Append value to string in DataFrame column if it's a duplicate
I have a Pandas DataFrame full of experimental data, and one of the columns is a string that encodes the experiment conditions. What isn't encoded in that string is which replicate run it indicates, which is arbitrary, but for further processing these strings need to be distinct. Here's an abbreviated expected input/output, my actual DataFrame is a few thousand rows:
Input:
#    condition  B  C   D
# 0  a_td_13_f  2  0   0
# 1  a_td_13_f  6  1   2
# 2  a_hw_19_f  9  2   4
# 3  a_hw_19_f  2  3   6
# 4  a_hh_10_f  1  4   8
# 5  a_hh_10_f  0  5  10
# 6  a_hh_10_f  5  6  12 

Output:
#    condition     B  C   D
# 0  a_td_13_f_r1  2  0   0
# 1  a_td_13_f_r2  6  1   2
# 2  a_hw_19_f_r1  9  2   4
# 3  a_hw_19_f_r2  2  3   6
# 4  a_hh_10_f_r1  1  4   8
# 5  a_hh_10_f_r2  0  5  10
# 6  a_hh_10_f_r3  5  6  12 

Additional information: there aren't always the same number of replicates, and it's not guaranteed that they're in adjacent rows.

You can just add an r after the dash to this answer. df['condition'] = (df['condition'] + '_r' + (df.groupby('condition').cumcount() + 1).astype(str))
